# ¿Cómo restringir rangos de tiempo en javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jsp

Tengo una gran duda.... ¿Es posible realizar la validación entre rangos de tiempos en Javascript? Supongamos que a partir de este código:

```
<h3>Inserte la Fecha para los Ingresos</h3>
<input type ="Date" id="fecha">
<h3>Hora de Visita para el Ingreso 1</h3>

<input type="time" id="tiempo11">
<input type="time" id="tiempo12">

<h3>Hora de Visita para el Ingreso 2</h3>

<input type="time" id="tiempo21">
<input type="time" id="tiempo22">


<h3>Hora de Visita para el Ingreso 3</h3>

<input type="time" id="tiempo31">
<input type="time" id="tiempo32">

<br>
<br>
<br>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Reservar</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>


</script>
```

Necesito que se valide que el rango de horas que para `tiempo11` y `tiempo12` no se cruce con `tiempo21` y `tiempo22`, lo mismo para `tiempo31` y `tiempo32`. O mejor aún si dentro de la etiqueta `<p id="demo"></p>`, se le notifique al usuario sobre no superponer estas horas para la fecha seleccionada. ¿Es posible hacerlo dentro del Javascript y mostrarlo inmediatamente? ó ¿tengo que programarlo desde el lenguaje del lado del servidor? (preferiblemente JSP o PHP). Y de ser posible en alguno de los dos casos ¿Cómo lo construirían?

Soy un muy novato para esto de la programación web. Ayuda...

Comment: Si quieres hacer la validación por javascript, te recomiendo que uses la clase **Date** para facilitar la validación de cruce de horas.
Por otro lado también lo podrías hacer mediante un store procedure en tu base de datos, usando **between** que seria mucho mas fácil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mira el ejemplo que muestras se puede resolver así:

He simulado un entorno donde la hora de apertura es las 9:30 y la de cierre 21:00.

Primero validamos que todas las citas estén dentro de este horario.

Después validamos que las hora de entrada del 2º sea mayor o igual a la salida del 1º y que la de entrada del 3º sea mayor o igual a la salida del 2º.

Espero que te sirva.

```js
const OPEN_HOUR = 9;
const OPEN_MINUTE = 30;

const CLOSE_HOUR = 21;
const CLOSE_MINUTE = 0;

const p = document.getElementById('demo');

function isValidHour(hour, minute) {
  return hour > -1 && hour < 24 && minute > -1 && minute < 60;
}

function validateDates(tiempo1, tiempo2) {
  if (tiempo1 && tiempo2 && tiempo1.value && tiempo2.value) {
    
    const now = new Date();
    const time1 = new Date(now);
    time1.setHours(tiempo1.value.split(':')[0])
    time1.setMinutes(tiempo1.value.split(':')[1])
    const time2 =new Date( now);
    time2.setHours(tiempo2.value.split(':')[0])
    time2.setMinutes(tiempo2.value.split(':')[1])
    // validamos que la fecha de ingreso sea menor que la de salida
    if (time1 < time2) {
      const open = new Date(now);
      open.setHours(OPEN_HOUR)
      open.setMinutes(OPEN_MINUTE);
      const close = new Date(now);
      close.setHours(CLOSE_HOUR);
      close.setMinutes(CLOSE_MINUTE);
      if (time1 >= open && time2 <= close) {
        p.innerHTML +='Éxito, hora de entrada y salida correcta';
        return true;
      } else {
        p.innerHTML +='Error, hora de entrada debe ser mayor que  '+ open.getHours()+ ':' + open.getMinutes() + ' y la salida menor que  '+ close.getHours()+ ':' + close.getMinutes();
      }

    } else {
     p.innerHTML +='Error, la hora de ingreso debe ser menor que la de salida';
    }
  } else {
   p.innerHTML +='Error, debes rellenar todos los datos';
  }
  return false;

}

function myFunction() {
  // Obtengo todos los inputs
  const tiempo11 = document.getElementById('tiempo11');
  const tiempo12 = document.getElementById('tiempo12');
  const tiempo21 = document.getElementById('tiempo21');
  const tiempo22 = document.getElementById('tiempo22');
  const tiempo31 = document.getElementById('tiempo31');
  const tiempo32 = document.getElementById('tiempo32');
  // valido el primer grupo
  const isValid1 = validateDates(tiempo11, tiempo12);
  const isValid2 = validateDates(tiempo21, tiempo22);
  const isValid3 = validateDates(tiempo31, tiempo32);
  
  // Todas estas fechas están dentro del horario de apertura 
  if(isValid1 && isValid2 && isValid3) {
    // valido que la hora de entrada del 2 sea mayor o igual que la hora de salida del primero, también que la hora de entrada del tercero sea mayor o igual que la salida del 3
     const salida1 = new Date();
    salida1.setHours(tiempo12.value.split(':')[0]);
    salida1.setMinutes(tiempo12.value.split(':')[1]);
    const entrada2 =new Date();
    entrada2.setHours(tiempo21.value.split(':')[0]);
    entrada2.setMinutes(tiempo21.value.split(':')[1]);
     const salida2 = new Date();
    salida2.setHours(tiempo22.value.split(':')[0]);
    salida2.setMinutes(tiempo22.value.split(':')[1]);
    const entrada3 =new Date();
    entrada3.setHours(tiempo31.value.split(':')[0]);
    entrada3.setMinutes(tiempo31.value.split(':')[1]);
    
    if(salida1 <= entrada2 && salida2  <= entrada3){
    console.log(salida1, entrada2, salida2, entrada3);
      p.innerHTML ='todo correcto';
    } else {
      p.innerHTML = 'La fecha de entrada del 2º debe ser mayor o igual a la de salida del 1º,y la de entrada del 3º debe ser mayor o igual que la salida del 2º';
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<h3>Inserte la Fecha para los Ingresos</h3>
<input type ="Date" id="fecha">
<h3>Hora de Visita para el Ingreso 1</h3>

<input type="time" id="tiempo11">
<input type="time" id="tiempo12">

<h3>Hora de Visita para el Ingreso 2</h3>

<input type="time" id="tiempo21">
<input type="time" id="tiempo22">


<h3>Hora de Visita para el Ingreso 3</h3>

<input type="time" id="tiempo31">
<input type="time" id="tiempo32">

<br>
<br>
<br>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Reservar</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>


</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Existen 6 casos en los que puede haber conflicto.  Sabiendo esto, puedes hacer esa validacion en javascript asi:

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "";
  var tiempo11 = document.getElementById("tiempo11").value;
  var tiempo12 = document.getElementById("tiempo12").value;
  var tiempo21 = document.getElementById("tiempo21").value;
  var tiempo22 = document.getElementById("tiempo22").value;
  var tiempo31 = document.getElementById("tiempo31").value;
  var tiempo32 = document.getElementById("tiempo32").value;
  
  if ((tiempo11 > tiempo21 && tiempo11 < tiempo22) || 
        (tiempo11 > tiempo31 && tiempo11 < tiempo32) || 
          (tiempo21 > tiempo31 && tiempo21 < tiempo32) || 
            (tiempo21 > tiempo11 && tiempo21 < tiempo12) || 
              (tiempo31 > tiempo21 && tiempo31 < tiempo22) || 
                (tiempo31 > tiempo11 && tiempo31 < tiempo12)) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Los rangos tienen conflicto";
  } 
}
```

```html
<h3>Inserte la Fecha para los Ingresos</h3>
<input type ="Date" id="fecha">
<h3>Hora de Visita para el Ingreso 1</h3>

<input type="time" id="tiempo11">
<input type="time" id="tiempo12">

<h3>Hora de Visita para el Ingreso 2</h3>

<input type="time" id="tiempo21">
<input type="time" id="tiempo22">


<h3>Hora de Visita para el Ingreso 3</h3>

<input type="time" id="tiempo31">
<input type="time" id="tiempo32">

<br>
<br>
<br>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Reservar</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Se puede hacer perfectamente en el browser.

Primero, el valor de los inputs de tipo time es del tipo `HH:mm`.

Yo partiría haciendo una función que compruebe si un valor está contenido dentro del rango definido por otros dos:

```
function isbetween(timeini,timefin, time) {
  return time>timeini && time<timefin;
}
```

De manera que capturando los valores del primer intervalo, digamos `01:01` y `02:02` podrías comprobar si el valor `01:30` es mayor a `01:01` y menor a `02:02` (lo que en este caso es cierto).

Aunque la comparación por strings en este caso funciona, yo encuentro que sería más ordenado convertir todo a segundos,  multiplicando la hora por 3600 y los minutos por 60. Para eso haces una función:

```
function toSeconds(time) {
  var hrs=time.split(':')[0],
      min=time.split(':')[1],
      secs = hrs*3600 + min*60;
      return secs;
}
```

Tu función de comprobación, entonces, debe capturar los valores de todos los inputs y usar `is_between` para verificar que:

- El inicio del intervalo2 no esté en el intervalo1
- El final del intervalo2 no esté en el intervalo1
- Lo mismo para el 3 vs el 1
- Lo mismo para el 3 vs el 2

Te dejo un ejemplo que, sin embargo, tiene una salvedad (que pongo al final)

```js
function toSeconds(time) {
  var hrs=time.split(':')[0],
      min=time.split(':')[1],
      secs = hrs*3600 + min*60;
      return secs;
}

function isbetween(timeini,timefin, time) {
  return time>timeini && time<timefin;
}

function myFunction() {
var demo=document.getElementById('demo')
  tiempo11=document.getElementById('tiempo11').value,
 tiempo12=document.getElementById('tiempo12').value,
 tiempo21=document.getElementById('tiempo21').value,
 tiempo22=document.getElementById('tiempo22').value,
 tiempo31=document.getElementById('tiempo31').value,
 tiempo32=document.getElementById('tiempo32').value,
 secs11=toSeconds(tiempo11),
 secs12=toSeconds(tiempo12),
 secs21=toSeconds(tiempo21),
 secs22=toSeconds(tiempo22),
 secs31=toSeconds(tiempo31),
 secs32=toSeconds(tiempo32);
  
  if(isbetween(secs11,secs12,secs21) || isbetween(secs11,secs12,secs22)) {
      demo.innerHTML='El intervalo 2 se superpone con el primer intervalo';
  }
 
}
```

```css
div {
  margin: 4px;
}
label {
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size:17px;
  margin-right:10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
<label>Inserte la Fecha para los Ingresos</label>
<input type ="Date" id="fecha">
</div>

<div>
  <label>Hora Ingreso 1</label>
  <input type="time" id="tiempo11" value="01:01">
  <input type="time" id="tiempo12" value="02:20">
</div>
<div>
  <label>Hora Ingreso 2</label>
  <input type="time" id="tiempo21" value="01:30">
  <input type="time" id="tiempo22" value="03:50">
</div>

<div>
  <label>Hora Ingreso 2</label>
  <input type="time" id="tiempo31" value="14:40">
  <input type="time" id="tiempo32" value="15:45">
</div>
<br>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Reservar</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

**Pero hay otro caso a contemplar**: si el periodo 2 contiene al 1 (empieza antes y termina después) entonces no se cumple que el 2 tope con el 1 (usando la función `isbetween`) pero sí se cumple que el 1 topa con el 2. Te dejo de tarea implementar una solución que asegure que:

- El periodo 2 no empieza ni termina dentro del periodo 1
- El periodo 2 no contiene al periodo 1
- El periodo 3 no empieza ni termina dentro del periodo 2 ni el 1
- El periodo 3 no contiene al periodo 2 ni al 1

Aunque la prioridad es arbitraria, este enfoque asume que el periodo 1 siempre tiene prioridad, y los otros dos deben adaptarse a él.

Hay una última comprobación, que es un poco obvia, que es **validar que un período no termine antes de su hora de inicio**.